# CSS - Changing one indirect child of parent with specific class

Tags: html, css, wordpress, class, parent-child

I'm trying to access the `h1` children of all `article` tags with the class `.category-member` without affecting any of its other children. So far, I've only managed to affect `.blog-content` and am having no luck with `h1`. Also, this is being used in WordPress, so I'm hoping to do this without adding a class to the `h1` so that any added blog posts will be colored depending on it's parent category class only.

Thanks in advance!

```
<article id="post-3107" class="post-3107 post type-post status-publish format-standard has-post-thumbnail hentry category-member span6 blog-article grid normal">                    
  <div class="row-fluid">
  <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
      <div class="content post_format_standart">
        <div class="top_c ">
          <h1><a href="http://wholeworldwater.dev:8080/another-test-post/">ANOTHER TEST POST</a></h1>
        </div>
        <div class="blog-content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam venenatis dolor eget est imperdiet efficitur. Donec et mollis sapien. Nam rhoncus urna dolo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</article>
```

Comment: .category-member .top_c + h1{ }     Selects the h1 imediately after .top_c

Comment: But the `<h1>` is within `.top_c`, not 'after it.'

Comment: I think he meant `category-member .top_c > h1{ } `

Answer (score 0):

Use a selector like `.category-member h1 { ... ... }`.  This will select everything that is a `h1` that has a parent that has class `category-member`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all - realized that my specific problem was that I was ignoring `h1`'s `a` tag. You were all spot on, though!

```
.category-member .top_c > h1 a{
  color: #d9382c;
}
```